# jquery как из кода элемента сделать jquery формат

Tags: jquery, chrome-extension

Получаю все элементы класса

```
var items = $('.item');
```

Дальше вывожу в консоль 2 элемент

```
console.log(items[1]);
```

И мне выдает тупо html код.
Делаю я так:

```
var items = $('.item:first');
console.log(items);
```

И уже выдает не html код а w.fn.init и что-то там дальше.
Так вот, с тем jquery форматом можно работать, .attr() например выполнить. А как с html кодом работать? Я хотел получить все элементы класса и у всех есть 1 атрибут data-title, его и хотел поочередно отправлять в функцию, вместе с элементом.

Comment: `console.log(items.eq(1));`

Comment: @Igor спасибо огромное!)